# HTACCESS | Adding a second rewrite rule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, vanity-url

I'm trying to write my .htaccess to support two vanity url's, the code will speak for itself as I'm not very  good with .htaccess.

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Upon going to for example http://website.com/home/test

I get a 404, but $_GET["p"] still returns back home if I go to just website.com/home.

Why am I getting a 404 when adding in my second variable in the url?

Comment: Because `^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$` matches a url that consists of alphanumerical characters followed by a slash.

Comment: I'm not good with htaccess. Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a 404 because `/home/test` does not match the expression `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?$`.  The second group after the first `/` exists beyond your `$` string terminator. You need to add a second `()` group, which is optional. I have replaced the `a-zA-Z0-9` character classes with `[^/]+` which matches everything up to the next slash.

The `(?:)` indicates a non-capturing group encompasing the first `/`, with a capturing group `()` inside it to retrieve the `$2` component. The entire construct is made optional with `?` before the final `$` terminator.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)/?)?$ index.php?p=$1&s=$2 [L,QSA]
```